# $(a, b) = (c, d)$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to use the definitions of equality of sets and equality of ordered pairs to prove this statement. Here's what I've come up with so far:

Assume $(a, b) = (c, d)$.

Then $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\} = \{c\}, \{c, d\}\}$ since $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ and $(c, d) = \{\{c\}, \{c, d\}\}$.

Since $\{a\}$ and $\{c\}$ are the only two singleton sets between the two sets respectively, $\implies \{a\} = \{c\}$.

Similarly, since $\{a, b\}$ and $\{c, d\}$ are the only non-songleton sets between the two sets respectively and $a=c$, $\implies b=d \space\blacksquare$

I imagine this is a bit of stretch of a proof, but any help/feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: What if $a = b$?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.  If you want a little more detail, you could say: $\{a\} \in (c,d)$ means either $\{a\} = \{c\}$ or $\{a\} = \{c,d\}$.  The latter is impossible by cardinality considerations.  So $\{a\} = \{c\}$. And so on.

Comment: @mihaild Aha, good catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define the ordered pair:

$$(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$$

Suppose that $(a,b) = (c,d)$. Then:

$$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$$

There are two possibilities. Either $\{a\} = \{c\}$ or $\{a\} = \{c,d\}$. We will explore each one of them carefully.

Suppose that $\{a\} = \{c\}$. Then, $a = c$. So, $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$ and $b = d$.

Suppose that $\{a\} = \{c,d\}$. Then, $\{c,d\}$ is a singleton and, therefore, $a = c = d$. So, $\{a,b\} = \{a\}$ and $a = b$. In other words, $a = c$ and $b = d$.

In all cases, it is the case that $a = c$ and $b = d$ if both ordered pairs above are equal. This proves the desired result.

As was mentioned in a comment, you cannot make undue assumptions when proving these things. To be more precise, if you're making any assumptions whatsoever, they must be fully justified.

Answer (score 3):

It’s tempting to reason the way you did, but technically, you don’t account for all possibilities. You’re diving into the proof with the (inaccurate) a priori assumption that $a \ne b$. Try to account for the alternative possibility, and see where this takes you in the course of the proof (hint: consider exhaustive cases).